# Not able to remove Widgets which were dynamically added to screen in Kivy

Tags: kivy, python-3.7

I am trying to add buttons dynamically when some text is typed on a text input. In order to achieve search select combo box in KIvy.
Even though i am able to add widgets when some text is typed , not able to remove those added widgets when the text typed is removed.

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix import dropdown
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
# from kivymd.app import MDApp
kivy.require('1.9.0')
from kivy.uix.dropdown import DropDown
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.base import runTouchApp
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager,Screen


class ScreenOne(Screen):
    def change_text(self,root,val):
        pass
    def create_dropdown(self,root,value):
        print("value is :" + value)
        if value == "":
            result = ""
            print(root.ids)
        else:
            lang = ["aa","aaa", "bsa","cds","dds", "ddyus"]
            result = list(filter(lambda x: x.startswith(value), lang))
            for i in range (0,len(result)):
                self.textinput = Button()
                self.textinput.id = 'textinput'+ str(i)
                self.textinput.text = result[i]
                self.textinput.size_hint= (.3, .06)
                self.textinput.font_size= '14sp'
                self.textinput.pos_hint= {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.8-(i+1)/10, }
                root.ids.screen1.add_widget(self.textinput)

sm = Builder.load_string("""


ScreenManager:
    ScreenOne:
        id: screen1
        name: "screen_one"
        TextInput:
            id: input1
            hint_text:'Select input Language'
            size_hint: (.3,.06)
            font_size: '14sp'
            pos_hint:{'center_x':0.5,'center_y':0.8,}
            on_text: root.ids.screen1.create_dropdown(root,input1.text)
            
""")
class demo(App):
    def build(self):
        return sm

app=demo()
# app.run()
runTouchApp(sm)
```

in UI when a is typed cahn see the below image
[image]

but when i clear the input text , i am still able to see the widgets added previously
[image]

I neet some logic to remove the added widgets when the text typed in input box is cleared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this:

```
result = list(filter(lambda x: x.startswith(value), #from your cod
lang)) #from your code
if result == [] :
    for widget in root.ids.screen1.children:
        root.ids.screen1.remove_widget(widget)
```